# How to add padding to a word in Pages?

Tags: pages

I want to add background to a specific word in Pages. I want to make a distance between this word and the edges of its background. Making distances horizontally on both sides of this word is more important to me. How can I add padding to a word in Pages?

PS: I know how to work the spacing section in Pages to add space before and after each paragraph. So it’s not my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is for one word and you are ready to abuse software features in unforeseen way then just enter two or whatever number of characters before and after the word and make their color same as background:

[image]

Comment: I want to create a specific character style for them to select a word and apply this style to it.
I can use your suggested method, but it takes a lot of time to apply it for lots of words. 
I always create paragraph and character styles for repetitive patterns.